# How do I get my Arduino to stop sending jumbled Unicode instead of numbers?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to collect data from a simple multimeter circuit, but instead of returning numbers my serial port is just outputting random Unicode symbols.

Here's my code:

```cpp
void setup() {
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(1200);
    int prevVal = 0;
    int timeVar = 0;
}
void loop() {
    int digisensorVal = digitalRead(2);
    int anasensorVal = analogRead(2) * 100;
    Serial.print("D" + digisensorVal);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println("A" + anasensorVal);
    delay(250);
}
```

And here's a sample of the output:

> ⸮L/⸮U⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮w⸮e⸮⸮⸮⸮1⸮⸮⸮⸮}⸮J⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮oޝ⸮Y⸮⸮⸮|s⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮є6x⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮y[⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮v⸮=⸮⸮⸮-⸮^⸮Y_z⸮⸮d⸮⸮⸮%ܿjV⸮~O⸮⸮G⸮⸮⸮⸮e⸮⸮U⸮⸮~+0⸮⸮⸮hh⸮s⸮
>   ⸮c⸮⸮⸮+⸮⸮io3:⸮5kλϣ
>   ,⸮g⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮>⸮⸮
>   ⸮yꨛ⸮v⸮N⸮⸮⸮=⸮⸮=⸮⸮⸮l⸮⸮g⸮g⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮s⸮U⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮=⸮ܳt⸮⸮⸮}⸮⸮'⸮˾⸮k⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮ᦒ⸮⸮⸮⸮ϓ߿gVp⸮⸮⸮⸮Y⸮⸮O⸮/F⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮q4⸮⸮_f⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮I|P⸮⸮⸮NE⸮~u⸮7⸮⸮⸮⸮g⸮⸮G~⸮⸮⸮⸮__@⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮C⸮⸮⸮k⸮T⸮o/⸮t^⸮~⸮{}⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮'h=⸮ϸ~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮*s⸮s⸮l⸮o5⸮^⸮⸮⸮w9{]⸮⸮q~⸮⸮⸮,⸮*⸮⸮c⸮2_⸮⸮⸮⸮o6k)ޏ⸮k⸮ׇ⸮i⸮⸮m⸮⸮:⸮⸮⸮⸮|⸮⸮??⸮⸮⸮⸮3⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮^⸮⸮ڏ⸮⸮⸮⸮l⸮*⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮H⸮~⸮>⸮⸮z⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮OwM;⸮⸮l⸮*⸮
>   ⸮sr⸮S⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮ׂٶ⸮⸮~⸮{⸮⸮]⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮i⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮[⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮Nz⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮k⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮g⸮k⸮⸮⸮i3ɵ⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮]⸮2ϪWކ⸮i>⸮gu⸮⸮ӵ⸮?⸮̥⸮⸮m⸮⸮|⸮⸮⸮⸮Wɓ⸮⸮⸮[⸮⸮O㠑_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮/⸮M⸮⸮_⸮⸮gwF⥷⸮⸮yn⸮P⸮⸮-⸮⸮⸮*N⸮⸮⸮=⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮>J⸮}⸮⸮&⸮⸮⸮C⸮HG翎⸮/⸮⸮⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮^⸮⸮,⸮)[⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮У⸮⸮}⸮ޯ⸮⸮⸮⸮7*⸮⸮⸮⸮ó⸮U:~⸮⸮ns⸮⸮z⸮⸮n⸮⸮G|޿ӳ꓊⸮⸮}⸮⸮L⸮~⸮⸮KI⸮⸮G⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ӏ⸮⸮⸮⸮u6⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮Ӊ۾⸮⸮9⸮zVΆ럿⸮⸮⸮ۘ⸮⸮T⸮<⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮/⸮⸮⸮⸮xG~⸮V⸮⸮u+N⸮⸮ݫ⸮⸮⸮cv~⸮⸮⸮W⸮

Answer (score 1):

```
Serial.println("A" + anasensorVal);
```

This needs to be done in two lines. You're adding the sensor value to a pointer value and sending whatever garbage is pointed to at the memory location that adds up to. And it definitely isn't what you want. This isn't Java. You can't just add strings with a + like that.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
Serial.println("A" + anasensorVal);
```

you are not actually printing number, but a string from some place in the memory starting at the address of "A" +  value of "anasensorVal" and thus you will get some garbage.

You are trying to add an integer to a pointer to char(and likely move beyond the end of the string "A"), that's not what you want.

The usual way of formating output on arduino:

```
Serial.print("A");
Serial.println(anasensorVal);
```

Alternatively, you can define a stream operator for the Serial object, see https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/StreamingOutput how to do that and then format output like this:

```
Serial << "A" << anasensorVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an int type and character type in `Serial.print` is messing up the format of the data you are trying to print to the monitor.